# Convert Azimuth and Elevation to X & Y angles

Tags: mathematics

I’m trying to control a 2 axis solar tracker using a microcontroller with an internal IMU.

I can calculate sun azimuth and elevation but how do I convert them to X & Y angles that I can compare with the internal IMU X & Y values?